On a QGIS layout, is it possible to obtain a scalebar's zero coordinates?
I have several pages on a layout, each of them has a scale bar. These scale bars' widths aren't fixed, they vary on each page (they are set to "Fit segment width", as you can see on the image with one scale bar's settings). These scale bars also have right and left segments, and the scale bar's origin or zero point is between them.
On each page, I need to align several layout items with each scale bar's origin point. To do it automatically, I'd love to be able to tell these items to use each scale bar's origin's X and Y coordinates. (I guess these coordinates would be related to each page, right?)
THIS IS A SCALE BAR WITH ITS POSITION SETTINGS:

AS AN EXAMPLE OF HOW I WANT TO ALIGN ITEMS, THIS IS A TEXT BOX, ALIGNED TO THE SCALE BAR'S ZERO, WITH ITS POSITION SETTINGS:

So, is there an expression to extract these coordinates? In order to pass them as parameters for each different page's items to be aligned.

Could you provide either a layout, or the settings of your scale bar, as well as the settings of at least one other item?

Ok, thanks for the help. Will a couple of images added to my question do?

I guess you should post them first, then we see if it's enough.

Hey, @Babel, thanks for commenting. I added the images to the original post. Are they useful?

Hey, @Erik, I added the images to the original post. Are they useful?
